# https posting, not receiving the expected value as result

Tags: java, android, http, https, http-post

I finally got my application to "seemingly" post to https. However, every time that i post and get the result, the result is -200. This result is the response from the server telling me that i need to authenticate. The result would be positive, if i authenticate correctly. And i am posting to authenticate... so the response is just telling me that it is failing. I have talked to the server admin and he said that i probably have a space somewhere in actual post.

My question is, how do i check the full message that is being posted? Basically, how can i check to make sure that what i put in the URL in a web browser, is the same as what is being posted in the application? Right now, i have it printing some of it, but how do i know that ALL of that message is correct. Starting from the "https" all the way to the very end of the message.

Thanks in advance!! Any help is appreciated and if you see anything wrong with what i currently have, please let me know! THANK YOU!

The URL should look like this when posting:

> https://ipaddress/health_monitoring/admin.php?action=authentication&username=uName&password=pWord

```
//my database helper class
public class SmartDBHelper {
    private static SmartDBHelper sDBHObject;

    private SmartDBHelper() {

    }

    public static synchronized SmartDBHelper getSDBHObject() {
        if(sDBHObject == null) {
            sDBHObject = new SmartDBHelper();
        }
        return sDBHObject;
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

    /* this function is to authenticate with the database
     * it returns the id_subject, if it is greater than 0
     * authentication was successful.
     */
    public static synchronized int authenticate(String uName, String pWord) {
        Map<String, String> tempMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        tempMap.put("action", "authentication");
        tempMap.put("username", "uName");
        tempMap.put("password", "pWord");
        try {
            String tempUrl = "https://ipaddress/health_monitoring/admin.php";
            String result = post(tempUrl, tempMap);
            Log.v("smartdbhelper post result", result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // always verify the host - dont check for certificate
    final static HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
            }
    };

    /**
     * Trust every server - dont check for any certificate
     */
    private static void trustAllHosts() {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }
            } };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            try {
                    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                    HttpsURLConnection
                                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private static String post(String urlString, Map formParameters)
    throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
        DataOutputStream ostream = null;

        trustAllHosts();
        URL tempUrl;
        tempUrl = new URL(urlString);
        HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) tempUrl.openConnection();
        https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);

        https.setRequestMethod("POST");
        https.setDoInput(true);
        https.setDoOutput(true);
        ostream = new DataOutputStream(https.getOutputStream());

        if(formParameters != null) {
            Set parameters = formParameters.keySet();
            Iterator it = parameters.iterator();
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

            for(int i = 0, paramCount = 0; it.hasNext(); i++) {
                String parameterName = (String) it.next();
                String parameterValue = (String) formParameters.get(parameterName);

                if(parameterValue != null) {
                    parameterValue = URLEncoder.encode(parameterValue);
                    if(paramCount > 0) {
                        buf.append("&");
                    }
                    buf.append(parameterName);
                    buf.append("=");
                    buf.append(parameterValue);
                    ++paramCount;
                }
            }
            Log.v("smartdbhelper adding post parameters", buf.toString());
            Log.v("smartdbhelper adding post parameters", https.toString());
            ostream.writeBytes(buf.toString());
        }

        if( ostream != null ) {
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
        }
        Object contents = https.getContent();
        InputStream is = (InputStream) contents;
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int c;
        while((c = is.read()) != -1) {
            buf.append((char)c);
            Log.v("smartdbhelper bugger", buf.toString());
        }
        https.disconnect();
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Stripping out all the code which avoids SSL name validation would help make your question more readable.

Comment: I left that stuff in there so that people can examine the full part of my code that could affect the problem, since i am not sure that it works correctly yet. I was having trouble posting to https before this problem started happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was! I was actually posting to http before i was appending the post to the url... oops.

Fixed code for the post is listed below for those that need an example.

```
private static String post(String urlString, Map formParameters)
throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
    DataOutputStream ostream = null;

    trustAllHosts();
    URL tempUrl;
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    if(formParameters != null) {
        Set parameters = formParameters.keySet();
        Iterator it = parameters.iterator();
        //StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        for(int i = 0, paramCount = 0; it.hasNext(); i++) {
            String parameterName = (String) it.next();
            String parameterValue = (String) formParameters.get(parameterName);

            if(parameterValue != null) {
                parameterValue = URLEncoder.encode(parameterValue);
                if(paramCount > 0) {
                    buf.append("&");
                }
                buf.append(parameterName);
                buf.append("=");
                buf.append(parameterValue);
                ++paramCount;
            }
        }
        Log.v("smartdbhelper adding post parameters", buf.toString());


    }
    urlString = urlString + "?" + buf;
    Log.v("smartdbhelper url string", urlString);
    tempUrl = new URL(urlString);
    HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) tempUrl.openConnection();
    https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
    Log.v("smartdbhelper adding post parameters", https.toString());
    https.setRequestMethod("POST");
    https.setDoInput(true);
    https.setDoOutput(true);
    ostream = new DataOutputStream(https.getOutputStream());
    ostream.writeBytes(buf.toString());


if( ostream != null ) {
    ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
    }
    Object contents = https.getContent();
    InputStream is = (InputStream) contents;
    StringBuffer buf2 = new StringBuffer();
    int c;
    while((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        buf2.append((char)c);
        Log.v("smartdbhelper bugger", buf2.toString());
    }
    https.disconnect();
    return buf2.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of -200 indicating a need to authenticate.  Is that a custom response code sent by your server?  Generally you would get a 401 or the like when you need to authenticate.

Here are the [standard HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Additionally when you post parameters, they do not get added to the end of the URL so your URL will not look like what you put at the top of the question.

It will simply be `https://ipaddress/health_monitoring/admin.php`

Comment: It is a custom response. How can i check that there are no extra characters put into the post? I have the post being printed to the screen and i do not see any extra characters, but the admin says i am probably putting an extra space somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing I just noticed is this:

```
tempMap.put("username", "uName");
tempMap.put("password", "pWord");
```

You are placing the constant values `"uName"` and `"pWord"` into the map instead of the variables.  It should be:

```
tempMap.put("username", uName);
tempMap.put("password", pWord);
```

You may also want to call `.trim()` on the params first to make sure there is no extra whitespace.